# Auto populate multiple rows from a drop down list

Tags: excel, vba

I have been searching the internet for hours and can find nothing to answer my question so I thought I would try here in the hope that someone can point me in the right direction. Here is what I am trying to accomplish:...

I am building a self-calculating score sheet for my local Darts League. The sheet is just about finished except for the team data.

*Example:*
I have a dropdown list in cell **A4** which contains the 8 teams in my division

The list is populated through data validation from another sheet. This other sheet also contains 8 columns (1 for each team) containing the names of the players in that team. Each column is named for the team.

I want to be able to select a team from the list in **A4** and automatically have their players inserted into cells **A24** thru **A36**.

If anyone has any idea how to do this or knows of a tutorial to get me started, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks to all who reply.

I need to make a correction in the explanation above... I should have realized the mistakes before post... I apologize

1. The drop downs are in cell A5 for the home team and K5 for the Away Team
2. The drop downs contents are on second sheet named 'Teams'
3. The players content is on sheet 3 named 'Players' with the team names as headers in the first row.

I have attached a copy of the worksheet filled in manually to show what I want to do, which is the populate rows 58 to 69 in columns A and I according to the team selected in the drop downs.

I'm pulling my hair out with this one.!

Thanks again.[Download Worksheet from Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndl0ntkxic39xe0/SIDL-Scoresheet%28Self-Calculating%29.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: I think you can accomplish this even without VBA. Check the VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP spreadsheet functions.

Comment: I looked up both, but still can't figure it out...

Answer (score 0):

**edited** after OP's edit of actual data structure

place the following code in the code pane of the "Main" worksheet (i.e. that one that has drop down lists in its cells "A5" and "K5":

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Address(False, False) <> "A5" And Target.Address(False, False) <> "K5" Then Exit Sub '<-- exit if changed cell is not "A4"

    With Range("A58:A69").Offset(, IIf(Not Intersect(Target, Columns("K")) Is Nothing, 8, 0)) '<--| reference range you want to write result corresponding to validation cell choice (offset 8 columns if target is "K5")
        On Error GoTo ExitSub '<-- properly handel possible errors and be sure to restore events handling you're going to disable next line
        Application.EnableEvents = False '<--| disable events handling not to have this sub got called in an infinite recursive loop
        .Value = Worksheets("Players").Rows(1).Find(what:=Target.Value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count).Value '<--| write in referenced range the content of Player worksheet range in rows 2 to 12 in column whose header in row 1 matches target value
    End With
ExitSub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True '<-- restore event handling

End Sub
```

The code pane of a worksheet can be accessed as follows:

- open VBA editor (ALT+F11 while in Excel UI)
- open Project Manager (CTRL+R) window
- in Project Manager Window expand the "Microsoft Excel Objects" node
- double click the tree item corresponding to "Main" worksheets
- the worksheet code pane is than available at the left
- copy above code and paste it in the code pane

Comment: The VBA is way beyond me... I have to learn VBA before I can understand what's going on here...

Comment: How can I upload a copy of the actual worksheet? Perhaps It will be easier to see what I am trying to do... I am at best a basic Excel user...

Comment: see [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for how to improve your question. There you'd find how to link screenshots or other things

Comment: @user2037250, see edited answer. If it fulfilled your question please mark answer as accepted. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank everyone for their kind assistance. It got me thinking about the options... when finally I found an answer that was so simple I fell off my chair!

It works like a charm!

***=INDEX(Players!$A:$H,ROWS($A$1:$A2),MATCH(A$5,Players!$A$1:$H$1,))***

Still some small things to work out, but it gets the job done!

Thanks again to everyone!